# React on Unity component reset

Tags: unity-game-engine, reset

I wrote a script which replaces a material on an object with a custom one. Whenever the component is destoryed or disabled, the original material is placed back.
However, whenever I use the reset button, it breaks the system since the stored original material is lost.

Is there a way to react to this reset by first placing the original material back somehow?

Thanks!

Comment: What is your intend with the reset button? If you just want a button on the component to get the original material back, you could add a custom button.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a custom Reset() method for your MonoBehaviour.
[Reset in MonoBehaviour](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Reset.html)

Just set the original material in this method.

Comment: I cannot do that since all fields get reset to its original value. The stored material is thus discarded and I cannot reset it in the Reset method since its field is already cleared first.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a button to change the material to the original, you can use the context menu attribute:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class MaterialSwitcher : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Material _originalMaterial

    [ContextMenu("restore to original material")]
    void RestoreOriginalMaterial()
    {
        GetComponent<Renderer>().material = _originalMaterial
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats what i have now indeed! Im just wondering if it is possible to react on reset because currently it breaks the system.